# Reading row values instead of field values with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, values

I use this piece of code to read the values of fields:

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

features = lyr.getFeatures()

for feat in features:
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    print attrs[1]
```

How can I read values of rows instead? and how can I loop through each row and print out the values like in a list for each row?

Comment: Replace the 2 last lines by `print feat.attributes()` That's a list of values for each row being printed. You can access a specific row, for example by its unique `id`.

Comment: @GermánCarrillo you should add it as answer